# Is there any GOTO ability in Jupyter notebook/lab or contrib extensions?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, goto

I have a jupyter notebook for a machine learning project. It has, say, 20 cells. What I'd like to automate is, run the first 19 cells, change a global variable at the last cell, then run all the cell from 2 onward over again with this global variable change.

If there was some kind of GOTO functionality where I could tell a cell to go to another after completing this would be perfect, but workarounds could be useful as well.

What I'm trying to avoid is having to either:
- duplicate all cells after global variable change or
- require manually performing this so that I can't just select 'run all'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute cells programmatically by running some Javascript in the notebook.  Put the following in the 21st cell in the notebook:

```
%%javascript
// run the first 19 cells
var i;
for(i=0; i<19; i++) {
    Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([i]);
}

// set the global in the 20th cell:
Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([19]);

// run 2nd through 19th cells again:
for(i=1; i<19; i++) {
    Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([i]);
}
```